# how to filter role from children of array based on other array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I need to filter role from children of array based on other array, but i'm still confused on using filter in my case

this is the base array :

```
arr1 = [
  {
    name: 'test1',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'one',
        role: 'menu_one'
      },
      {
        name: 'two',
        role: 'menu_two'
      },
      {
        name: 'three',
        role: 'menu_three'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'four',
        role: 'menu_four'
      },
      {
        name: 'five',
        role: 'menu_five'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

this is accepted role :

```
arr2 = ['menu_one', 'menu_three', 'menu_four']
```

this is what i'am trying to accomplish:

```
arr1 = [
  {
    name: 'test1',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'one',
        role: 'menu_one'
      },
      {
        name: 'three',
        role: 'menu_three'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'test2',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'four',
        role: 'menu_four'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I try this and is not work, did i use it wrong?

```
var result = arr1.filter(function(item) {
  return arr2.includes(item.children.role); 
})
```

I hope someone can help my case

Comment: Can you add what you've tried so far? This is important for us to assist you. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), along with [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the required result.

In each iteration, we'd filter the children of each item, by checking that their role is present in the arr2 array.

```js
arr1 = [ { name: 'test1', children: [ { name: 'one', role: 'menu_one' }, { name: 'two', role: 'menu_two' }, { name: 'three', role: 'menu_three' } ] }, { name: 'test2', children: [ { name: 'four', role: 'menu_four' }, { name: 'five', role: 'menu_five' } ] }, { name: 'test3 - no children' } ]

arr2 = ['menu_one', 'menu_three', 'menu_four'];

const result = arr1.map(({ name, children }) => { 
    return { 
        name, 
        children: children ? children.filter(child => arr2.includes(child.role)) : null
    };
})

console.log('Result:', result)
```

You could also improve efficiency (if arr2 is big!) by creating a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to check if the role is present in the item.

```js
arr1 = [ { name: 'test1', children: [ { name: 'one', role: 'menu_one' }, { name: 'two', role: 'menu_two' }, { name: 'three', role: 'menu_three' } ] }, { name: 'test2', children: [ { name: 'four', role: 'menu_four' }, { name: 'five', role: 'menu_five' } ] }, { name: 'test3 - no children' } ]

arr2 = ['menu_one', 'menu_three', 'menu_four'];
let roleSet = new Set(arr2);

const result = arr1.map(({ name, children }) => { 
    return { 
        name, 
        children: children ? children.filter(child => roleSet.has(child.role)) : null
    };
})

console.log('Result:', result)
```

Comment: thank you this really works, I forgot what if there is data that does not have children. so I modified it like this `children: children ? children.filter(child => rolset.has(child.role)) : null` 
is this ok?

Comment: Oh yes, let me update the answer to reflect those changes!